# How to ESCAPE "comma" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

**EDIT1:**

```
btnDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Format(@"return DeleteRow('{0}',{1},{2},{3});", e.Row.ClientID, e.Row.RowIndex, DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Id"), "'" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Name") + "'"));
```

edit:

i get this error:

**Message: Unterminated string constant**

i am passing the value from code behind and some of my text have somethinh lke this:

**`Foo3, In.c`**

```
   //javascript
    function DeleteRow(rowId, rowIdx, Id, Name) {         
        var textForMessage = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record with the name: \n{0} \n{1}');";
        //removed code...  
       return result;
    }
```

Comment: Your code looks... strange. You define parameters which you don't use. You initialize a local variable which you don't use. And you return a variable which you have not defined... If the text you have is `Foo3, In.c` then where is this value passed? Even if it is passed as one of the parameters, you are not doing anything with them... Please provide a more complete/correct/whatever example.

Comment: i removed some of the code for readability

Comment: But you've also removed any indication of an actual issue. Please post full code that demonstrates the issue, not merely the part that you *assume* represents whatever issue you're having. In other words, please provide a working example.

Comment: Your update doesn't look like javascript to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do nothing. A comma has no special meaning inside a JavaScript string.

Comment: Yup, you would want to escape single quotes though. You can escape single quotes with a "\" ... so ' becomes \' in the javascript that you emit.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to escape the comma. You should surround the **entire string** with quotes:

```
'Foo3, In.c'
```

If this string is inside another string which is also single-quoted you may need to escape the quotes.

Comment: i have updated my question, i am passing the name with surround with single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If the error is client side you can solve it by having:

```
btnDelete.Attributes["onclick"] = String.Format("return DeleteRow('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}');", e.Row.ClientID, e.Row.RowIndex, DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Id"), DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Name").ToString().Replace("'", "\'"));
```

If it's server side, please post the full error message plus stack trace.

Comment: yes the error is at client side and if i comment the server side line code which is  `(btnDelete ....... )` than it works fine without any javascript error, but if uncomment the server side code than i do see the error ` Message: Unterminated string constant `

Comment: @Abu did you try with the exact line I posted instead of the line you have?

Answer (score 0):

`\x2c`

Useful in ajax.

```
function myfunction(id, str_URL) {
     $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: str_URL,
         success: function(t) {
             var link = "<a href=\x22JavaScript:MyJava(\x22Param1\x22\x2c\x22Param2\x22)\x22>Link text</a>";
         }

     });
}
```

`\x22` is `"` (quote)

Just reference the Hex column in the ascii table.

http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif

Comment: using , instead of \x2c gives browser error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to escape a throw error due to comas that you need in a non quoted could be string datatype.
say you needed it  that way post.example, + post.example,

```
  var comma =",";

post.example.concat(comma) + post.example.concat(comma)
```

Using concat method will concatenate any variable type.